# MediaPlugin saves image under Application diroctory folder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using MediaPlugin to capture image and upload back to server. But, my problem is the MediaPlugin by default it saves the images under Application directory folder. i.e. "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.plugin.mediatest/files/Pictures/Test/".

So, without knowing the user. Silently, the app might be eating up the phone memory. If we want to address this issue what is the best solution we can give. Appreciate if you could share your expertise.

Comment: It depends upon what your app (and user) needs do w/ the image, only you can answer that.

Comment: @SushiHangover, updated my initial question. Please refer.

Comment: The question still remains, for how long do you need to keep the image, if you are uploading it to a server, then maybe it is appropriate to delete it after an upload success, maybe you are OCRing it, delete it after the text is extracted but if that fails, maybe you need the user to edit the image, etc...  Your question (nor update) does not cover what you are doing with the image after its upload and thus only you can determine when the app should programmatically delete them or if it should be a choice given to the user.

Comment: You could easily ask the user where to save the captured photos, and IF they want them to be saved locally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am keeping a copy inside the Album/Gallery for future references. My concern is, can we define the location instead the default application package directory. 
Because, saving inside the default directory might cost the phone memory (without knowing user) unless we explicitly delete immediate after upload.